# Using Framer-Motion, how to animate multiple object circle around a center point

Tags: reactjs, animation, canvas, css-animations, framer-motion

I have looked through all the available documentations and haven't found any examples as complex as what i'm trying to make.

I want to be able to create different shapes(trajectories) and have object follow their path. For example have multiple boxes circle around a center point for infinite amount of time.

Im not good at math, but I guess I would need to have a functions that updates the orbiting objects x and y coordinates? That function would also be responsible for calculating the distance between the center point and the space between multiple objects on the same trajectory?

I chose Framer-Motion library to make such animations easier to manage.

Is my thinking correct here?